# Creating a delete route for page controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, link-to

I have an application that creates page templates. There are many pages (user templates) in a User's account.  I am getting the following error when I click my delete button:

**browser**:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [DELETE] "/pages/1"
```

**html**:

```
 <%= link_to 'Delete', page_path(page), :method => :delete, 
                                        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?", 
                                        :remote => true, 
                                        class: 'btn btn-table-action btn-danger' %>
```

**controller**:

```
def destroy
  @page = Page.find(params[:attributeID])
  @page.destroy

  render :index
end
```

**routes**:

```
    pages GET    /pages(.:format)                                 pages#index
          POST   /pages(.:format)                                 pages#create
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)                        pages#edit
     page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)                             pages#show
          PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)                             pages#update
```

**UPDATE**:

**routes.rb**:

```
resources :pages, only: [:index, :show, :create, :edit, :update] do
  resource :optin_integration, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

Where do I begin to create a delete route and make my delete button functional in Rails?

Comment: Can you post what your `config/routes.rb` file looks like?

Comment: I included `:pages` in the routes.rb file

Comment: Yea then do what @screenmutt has suggested and add :destroy to `only`

Comment: I love stackoverflow. I got a different error now but that did the trick. Thanks @liamneesonsarmsauce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the pages resource available on destroy.

```
resources :pages, only: [:index, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  resource :optin_integration, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

Here is a nice [tutorial on Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your `config/routes.rb` file you need to add

```
resources :pages
```